# Windows phone app publish issues

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone 8 application. All goes well app published on app store but when i download app from app store it starts and crashed after few seconds.

I deployed the "XAP" file which was uploaded to app store on my device, it worked fine.

Am i missing something? Please need Help

EDIT:

"CLR_EXCEPTION_SQLite.SQLiteException" exception was causing the issue. Can anybody help abut this exception i don't know what is causing this.

Regards.

Comment: you may be missing some capabilities check all required capapblities

Comment: @SmartDeveloper All the capabilities from manifest are there in app details.

Comment: Are both builds are realease one? You may have done some work for debugging might not be working at release version. Please do check release version.

Comment: @vits. Yes both are releases, as i said i just to be sure i deployed XAP file on device it is working fine.

Comment: Both are on same device? please uninstall deployed app before installing app from store.

Comment: @vits Yes i did the same.

Comment: have you tried on some other device?

Comment: @vits not yet. But have the same thinking.

Comment: are there any crash logs ?

Comment: Is your app taking more than 4 sec to use at launch.?

Comment: You should add some kind of crash-log (app unhandled exception handler).
Also, try it on a "not-developer-unlocked" device.

Comment: And: If you use network services, maybe you installed some additional certificates on your device?

Comment: Hi add bugsense api and republish your app. You will notify when an error is occured.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. There were crash counts against the app. But i am not sure if it still goes with any other device because currently doesn't have one :( .

Comment: it also crashing on non developer device.

Comment: I was getting "CLR_EXCEPTION_SQLite.SQLiteException". Dnt know which problem is causing this. Can you guys help.

Comment: To add information to the question, edit it. (And the crash log is still missing.)

Comment: @CL. sorry that was my mistake. but the other question you mentioned duplicate of this was totally different.